# laravel check if variable session

Tags: php, laravel

is it possible to check variable of the session like this
my session is `{{Session::get('package_id')}}` and this display number but I want to it like this

```
  @if(Session::has('4'))
 <label>Your package is Free do you want to update?</label>@endif
```

Answer (score 3):

The proper way to use something like this

```
@if(Session::get('package_id')==4)
   package is free
@else
   Do another thing
@endif
```

or

```
<label>{{ Session::get('package_id')==4 ? 'Free':'Paid' }}</label>
```

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting '(' (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\

Comment: <label>{{ (Session::get('package_id')==4) ? 'Free':'Paid' }}</label>